# Visible binding and dynamic css binding

Tags: javascript, css, knockout.js

In this example, Knockout is working as intented. I'm looking for an alternative way of achieving the goal of having a **dynamically** filled grid with CSS class `.last` on every second item. In a way, I'm probably looking for a different approach.

### JSFiddle with description

My problem illustrated on http://jsfiddle.net/96vdD/7/ and described here:

Three `people` pass through the `foreach`. Adding three `div`s to the grid.
Dynamically, Knockout assigns a css class of `last` to every second `div` that comes out of the `foreach`.

At the same time, each `people`s visibility property decides whether or not (s)he will be displayed in the grid.

The CSS will strip the margin of every `.last` `div` in the grid, to prevent each second `div` from being moved to the next 'row'. A common layout technique in CSS.

See what happens when you change Charles' visibility to `true` and run the JSFiddle.

### Problem

The second person in the example, Charles, is not shown in the grid (because his property `visible` is set to `false`). However, Denise is still moved to the next row. 
Knockout adds a `style="display:none"` to Charles, but also applies the `class="last"` rule to him, while ideally I would like Denise to receive the `class="last"` as visually she is the second `people` in the grid.

### Question

How can I have Knockout ignore `!visible` elements when applying the `class="last"` rule?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a computed array of only visible people:

```
self.visiblePeople = ko.computed(function() {
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.people(), function(person) {
        return person.visible;
    });
});
```

then bind on it in your html:

```
<div class="wrapper" data-bind="foreach: visiblePeople">
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/96vdD/8/

Comment: However, why would I need to create a computed array? I think using just `ko.utils.arrayFilter` does the job too (http://jsfiddle.net/96vdD/10). 

What is the added value of storing this in a computed array?

Comment: If the `people` array changes (items added or removed), the computed version will also updated the html but `ko.utils.arrayFilter` version will not. The purpose of computed observables is that they track changes within other observables used for the computation and notify subscribers according to that.